# Can pymongo detect if a collection is capped?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm writing functionality in Python to ensure the existence, type, and size of mongodb collections.  Most of these collections are capped.  I know that the mongo shell includes `mycollection.iscapped()`, but pymongo does not seem to support this functionality.

Within the context of pymongo, what is the best way to tell if a collection is capped collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `mycollection.options()` returns a dict with `'capped': True` if it's a capped collection.

Comment: Yeah, this way is better yet.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
# Where db is a pymongo database object
>>> db.command('collstats','mycollection')
{u'count': 308291, u'ns': u'mydb.mycollection', u'ok': 1.0, u'lastExtentSize': 83890176, u'avgObjSize': 256.10971452296695, u'max': 2147483647, u'totalIndexSize': 20407296, u'flags': 0, u'capped': 1, u'numExtents': 1, u'nindexes': 1, u'storageSize': 83890176, u'indexSizes': {u'tem_1_tbm_1_ip1_1_ip2_1_p2_1': 20407296}, u'paddingFactor': 1.0, u'size': 78956320}
```

Note `'capped': 1`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all the capped collections in my db I used:

```
def get_capped_collections(db):
    capped_collections = []
    for collection in db.collection_names():
        options = db[collection].options()
        if "capped" in options and options["capped"]:
            capped_collections.append(collection)
    return capped_collections
```